# Firebase User - updating profile without logging back in

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Authentication on my flask web app, and I want users of my site to be able to update their profile information - for now just profile pictures.

So, I have JavaScript function that takes the value of input field (photo url) and changes the photoURL field in Firebase.

It's working fine, however for it to take effect, the user has to re-log. Is there a way to update it without having to log out and log back in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Authentication communicates the user profile information as part of their ID token, which is loaded when they sign in and then automatically refreshed once per hour.

You can force a refresh by calling [`User.reload()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reload) or [`User.getIdToken(true)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getidtoken).

Comment: Thank you, not totally sure how, but it seems to be working!